# How to get span value onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**ON CHANGE** **get span value**

```
<div id='id2'><span>editable spane</span></div>
```

Comment: Please rephrase into something understandable :)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Pls rephrase

Comment: It all depends how the `span` is being edited (you can't just type into one like an `input`, generally speaking). More details would be welcomed.

Comment: An example of the code already tried would also be a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Ln5uf9y1/10/)

```
$('#id2 span').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand that you want span to be editable and get the value.

```
$('#id2 span').bind('click',
        function(){
            $(this).attr('contentEditable',true);
        });
 $('#id2 span').bind('blur',
          function(){
             $(this).attr('contentEditable',false);
              var pp = $(this).text();
              alert (pp);
        });
```